# mongodb не работает insertOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, база-данных, mongodb

код подключается к базе данных mongodb:

```
const dbConnect = async () => {
    try {
      await client.connect();
  
      const db = client.db('smile-tracker');
      const users = db.collection('users');
      return users;

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Database connect error!');
      console.log(e);
    }
}

const users = dbConnect();
await users.insertOne({user: username});
```

но мне выдает ошибку: users.insertOne is not a function

что делать ?

upd: раньше работало

Comment: какая библиотека используется?

Comment: @Grundy, mongodb

Comment: мне помогли на англоязычном stackowerflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256828/why-am-i-getting-error-insertone-is-not-a-function-in-mongodb